# Fresco - How to save images to local storage

Tags: android, android-image, fresco

My app needs to load images from local storage, apply some transformation and then save the transformed image back to local storage.

I am using Fresco to load images from storage. Everything works well, except that I'm not able to save images back to local storage.

This is what I'm doing to save images:

```
val imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline()
val dataSource = imagePipeline.fetchEncodedImage(imageRequest, context)
dataSource.subscribe(SaveBitmapSubscriber(), DefaultExecutorSupplier(1).forLocalStorageWrite())

class SaveBitmapSubscriber: BaseDataSubscriber<CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer>>() {
  override fun onFailureImpl(dataSource: DataSource<CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer>>) {
    Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "onFailureImpl")
  }

  override fun onNewResultImpl(dataSource: DataSource<CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer>>) {
    Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "onNewResultImpl")
  }
}
```

`onFailureImpl` is called every time. What am I doing wrong? Is this even the right way to do it? the documentation on the topic is scarce.

Answer (score 0):

In `onFailureImpl`, try `calling dataSource.getFailureCause()` and log that.
The exception should explain what went wrong.